# PHP Out of class pdo connection fails

Tags: php, class, pdo

I can not make the PDO connection outside the class. Browser gives 500 error. I want to write PDO codes in out class. I am doing global change, but it is not.

```
try { 
    $pas = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=tets', 'root', '123');   
    $pas->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
    $pas->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");  //  return all sql requests as UTF-8   
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
} 
/** 
 User Avatar Check 
**/ 
class Usercheck 
{ 
    public $sql , $paso; 


    public function __construct() 
    { 
        global $pas; 
        $this->paso =& $pas; 
    } 

    public function smf_members($whatid) 
    { 

        $this->sql = $this->paso->query("SELECT * FROM smf_members WHERE id_member = $whatid");         
    } 

    public function fetchcheck(){ 
        if ($this->sql) { 
            return $this->sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH); 
        } 
    } 
} 

$memberuser = new Usercheck(); 
$memberuser->smf_members('1');
```

Comment: What errors do you get exactly as I expect that will be your answer? Also as a side note, avoid those globals and pass your PDO object in directly as a dependency...

Comment: How can I be addicted?

Comment: What do you mean by addicted?

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone How can I use it outside of Global?

Comment: As above, pass it in as a dependency in the constructor instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good practice to use $global. There are many solutions to achieve what you want to do, and here is my approach.

1) Create a Connection Class to handle the PDO connectivity.

```
use PDO;
/**
* PDO Connection Classes
* Used by Database wrapper class to ensure that there is only one connection
*/
class Connection
{
    private $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME. ';charset=' . DB_CHARSET;
    private $conn;
    private $error;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO($this->dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->conn;
    }

}
```

2) Establish the PDO connection via your wrapper class __construct(), the __construct() also ensure that there is only one PDO connection is instantiated.

```
use PDO;
class UserCheck
{
    private $conn;
    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!$this->db) {
            $conn = new Connection();
            $this->db = $conn->getConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm highly recommend that you read this [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) on how to use PDO and many best practice tips.